# How to draw contours? python

Tags: python, opencv, find, draw, contour

I'm trying to draw ten largest contours in a source image but they dont appear.

```
import cv2
image_orig=cv2.imread('C:\Users\pc\Desktop\middleeast.jpg')
image_gray=cv2.cvtColor(image_orig,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
image_contours=image_orig.copy()
_, image_threshold=cv2.threshold(image_gray,0,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
_,contours,_=cv2.findContours(image_threshold,cv2.RETR_LIST,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
largest_contours = sorted(contours, key=cv2.contourArea)[-10:]
print len(largest_contours)
for contour in largest_contours:
    print cv2.contourArea(contour)
cv2.drawContours(image_contours, largest_contours, -1, (255,255,0), 3)
cv2.imshow('contours',image_contours)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

[Source image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J3MTn.jpg)

Comment: do you get any errors?

Comment: @Aaron no errors, the contours just dont appear after using the cv2.drawContours

Answer (score 0):

The code is working just fine. Because its a big image, you are unable to see. Add this line just before the `imshow` and you'll see the contours.

```
image_contours = cv2.resize(image_contours, None, fx=0.25,fy=0.25 , interpolation = cv2.INTER_CUBIC)
```